# Custom Activity in Journey Builder Slowing Down Performance

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, integration, journeybuilder, custom-activity

We are using a custom activity (Urban Airship integration) that sends push notifications to our customers. The Custom Activity is hosted on AWS.

We are seeing a throughput of about 6-10 emails per minute with a journey that looks like the following:

Data Extension Entry Source -> 15 min wait -> Split -> Email Send -> Wait 15min -> Urban Airship Custom Activity -> end

When we run the journey it takes half the time of the one with the Custom Activities.

With custom activities - 45k email sends in 24hours
Without custom activities - 41k email sends in 12 hours

Any advice on how we can improve this performance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We are using custom activities and have done testing involving them for up to 250k records in 1 hour, so there definitely isnt a limitation hard built in.
One thing that we found was slowing down (and the reason we did load testing) is that because of the synchronous and individual nature of the requests, the best thing to do is to design a custom activity which responds if the payload is in general ok, rather than doing the entire workload (essentially turning a synchronous process into asynchronous)

Using

JB -> Activity -> External API -> Activity -> JB

can add significant latency from the Journey Builder perspective.

Using

JB -> Activity -> JB (then from Activity continue to External API)

can reduce this significantly.

Of course, if you have information which you need to pull back this can be a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

@Doug I need to create a custom activity that I need to host on AWS. I am looking for the tech specs of the AWS instance that needs to be spun up. Is it mentioned somewhere?